# Decidablity of time complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Let $t:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a time constructible function with $t(n)\geq n + 100$. Show that there is no TM $T$ that given the gödel number of another TM $M$, decides wether or not M is time bounded by $t$. Can someone help me with this? I have no clue

Comment: Try something similar to the [proof of the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Sketch_of_proof).

Comment: @dkaeae Construct a TM $T'$ using the universal TM that works as follows: Given the gödel number $g$ of a TM $M$, $T'$ simulates $T$ on $g$. If $T$ returns "true" diverge, else do nothing. Now what happens if run $T'$ on it's own gödel number? does this work?

Comment: Yes, but there are two details you must be careful about: 1. instead of "do nothing" you want the machine to actually halt; 2. you have to somehow argue that, if $T'$ halts, then it takes less than $t(n)$ steps to do so.

Comment: Yes instead of simulating  T on g entirely I simulate it for t(|g|) steps therefor if T doesn't halt during this time period, T' halts with t(|g|) steps another contradiction

Comment: @Yamahari write an answer?